# How to add verification rules in jslint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, pmd, static-code-analysis

There are lots of options in jslint such as adsafe, fragment and so on. Set {adsafe: true} means let jslint verify the code according to the adsafe's rule. Here I have the same demand, I wanna add my own rule in jslint, but don't know how to do it for jslint. Moreover how to import all the rules for JsLint validator to Aptana 2.0 in one go and how to categorize these rules based on their severity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I suppose that to include your custom rules for JSLint you will have to get some modification in the original code of JSLint provided on [github](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint).

You can try to ask your question to Douglas Crockford directly in [the forum](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/) (see the reference to the link [here](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#feedback)).